# Slide div out of screen and other div into screen at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm building a mobile web app (APK not link) and I do know how to compile.
But I'd like to give it a real app feel (Effects).

I have this so far:

[image]

Is there a way to make that whole div slide left while another div slides right to fill in its place when I click a category? I'm looking for some simple code to do so, but I'll take anything.

Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I would suggest jQuery Mobile as it has all the features you wanted. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/transitions/

Comment: You can make each div `min-width: 100%;` and control the `margin-left:` on the first div. So when you want it to slide out have the first div change from `margin-left: 0%;` to `margin-left: -100%;` You can use `display: flex;` on the container/wrapper/parent so they don't wrap (stack on top of each other) as flex default is `flex-direction: row;` and `flex-wrap: nowrap` Other ways to go about it.

Comment: It would be nice if we could see some code

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen I've done that and it seems to work well! But, I'm not to good with `display: flex`. Could you explain how I can get only those two divs to be side by side but not able to scroll to the side?

Comment: Please review How to Ask a Question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Definitely need to post your code to your question so we can see what's happening and provide help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment here is some basic code to get you started.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('button-right')) {
    $('.block1').css('marginLeft', '-100%')
  } else { // hasClass button-left
    $('.block1').css('marginLeft', '0%')
  }
})
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.block1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.block2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {background-color: green;}
.button-left { left: 10px; }
.button-right { right: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks block1">div one (left)</div>
  <div class="blocks block2">div two (right)</div>
  <div class="button button-left">l</div>
  <div class="button button-right">r</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/kfbwxye8/